# how to refresh objects when i modify the HTML in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a page with jQuery content loaded, one of the div will be a slider

```
$('#slides').slides({
            preload: true,
            preloadImage: 'img/loading.gif',
            play: 6000,
            pause: 2500,
            hoverPause: true,
            slideSpeed: 1000,
            animationStart: function(current){
                $('.caption').animate({
                    bottom:-35
                },100);
            },
            animationComplete: function(current){
                $('.caption').animate({
                    bottom:0
                },200);
            },
            slidesLoaded: function() {
                $('.caption').animate({
                    bottom:0
                },200);
            }
        });
    });
```

now, the html is structured like this:

```
<div id"content">
   <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
```

I've got my page setup using jquery, when a user clicks on a link, it will load that page's content to the `#content`

```
var homepage = $("#content").html();
$("#content").load("myContent.html");
```

If the user goes back to home, simply :

```
$("#content").html(homepage);
```

but then the `$('#slides').slides();` doesn't work anymore.

how do I fix this?

[SlidesJS](http://slidesjs.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `complete` from `.load()` to check if your content has a `#slider` in it. If it does, initialize your `slides` plugin again.

```
var homepage = $('#content'),
options = {
    generateNextPrev: true,
    play: 1000
};
$('#slides').slides(options);

// Button click or something
$('#content').load('myContent.html', function(response, status, xhr) {
   if ($(response).find('#slider').length > 0) {
       $('#slides').slides(options);
   }
});
```

EDIT:

I was making a jsfiddle to demonstrate it, but jsfiddle is having server problems, so I made a codepen demo. http://codepen.io/Vestride/pen/LicKd. Calling the plugin again worked for me (although I was simulating ajax requests by just replacing the content with `.html()`).

Comment: i'm sure that the #slides will be there since it's stored in the "var homepage", what i'm asking is that how to make the slides(); work again after i've replaced the html and then put the same html(the one with #slides) back again

Comment: @Tom91136 also make sure you're calling `$('#slides').slides(options)`. If that doesn't work either, save your `homepage` variable before calling `slides()` I've edited the example above.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Put slider in a function,

```
function SliderCode()
{

$('#slides').slides({
            preload: true,
            preloadImage: 'img/loading.gif',
            play: 6000,
            pause: 2500,
            hoverPause: true,
            slideSpeed: 1000,
            animationStart: function(current){
                $('.caption').animate({
                    bottom:-35
                },100);
            },
            animationComplete: function(current){
                $('.caption').animate({
                    bottom:0
                },200);
            },
            slidesLoaded: function() {
                $('.caption').animate({
                    bottom:0
                },200);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

After setting hompage callslider function again,

```
$("#content").html(homepage);
SliderCode();
```

I didnot tested the code. hope it will work.

Comment: is there a better way to do this? like destroy the .slides(); first? how do i do that?

Comment: Or you can put slider in iframe. Then iframe in hompage html

Comment: i'm using XHTML 1.0 strict, i can't use iframes

Comment: Okay, Then I would suggest to show or hide the container element containing slider rather than setting the entire HTML all the times.

Comment: but it looses it's html when i do this: $("#content").load("myContent.html");

Comment: You mean when hiding or showing? or when using the code above? Okay got it. Put another parent div for your slider and show or hide it..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13972/discussion-between-tom91136-and-user970349)